# VSTS showing no pending changes but there are pending changes VS 2019

Tags: angular, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-code

I have angular 6 project mixed with .Net MVC. I use VSCODE for angular changes and VS2019 for .NET changes.

Every time open file for editing in VSCODE it show as read only and display message to overwrite as below

[image]

If overwrite file and saved. Changes does not shows in pending changes.

I need to go to VS, Check Out file before editing and then edit file which shows changes in pending changes. This process is really error-prone, I miss the files in every commit.

Does anyone help me, So I should be able to change file outside of Visual Studio and changes should be reflected in Pending Changes VSTS.

Comment: Are you using server workspace or local workspace?

Answer (score 0):

If you want TFS server detect changes done to files outside of Visual Studio, the simplest way is using **local workspace**.

[image: Detected adds under Pending Changes in Team Explorer]

Now anything else changes files outside Visual Studio, your workspace detects the `changes` automatically.

It also detects `adds` or `deletes` but you have to include them to your `Pending Changes` manually with the link under `Excluded Changes

If you are using **server workspace**, this is kind like when you are offline, you cannot work with your local files because they are read-only until you check them out. So highly recommend you switch to local workspace, you just need to make sure you open the files in VScode from a path which the same  as your TFS local worksapce. Then it will auto sync changes in Visual Studio and show in pending changes.

More  detailed information on the pros and cons of local and server workspaces, please refer our official [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks for you answer but its not working in my case. I still need to checkout the file first before its modifying outside of the Visual Studio then and only then its show in pending changes.

Comment: If you are using server workspace, this is kind like when you are offline, you cannot work with your local files because they are read-only until you check them out. So highly recommend you switch to local workspace, you just need to make sure you open the files in VScode from a path which the same  as your TFS local worksapce. Then it will auto sync changes in Visual Studio and show in pending changes. (tested and verified)
More  detailed information on the pros and cons of local and server workspaces, please refer our official link. See my update reply in above.